# Reading JSON from a file using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I try to simply read the json file, followed by the creation of the class object, but it does not work, BufferedReader does not even read the file, although in the examples it is directly passed to GSON, the dependency is added to the pom file.

json

```
{
  "student": [{
    "name": "Mark",
    "surname": "Ivanov",
    }, {
     
     "name": "Peter",
    "surname": "Ivanov",
  }]
}
```

Created classes

```
public class POJOStudents
{
     String name;
     String surname;
    
}

public class GeneralStudents {
    List<POJOStudents> student;

}


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

    public class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
    
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\student.json"));
            GeneralStudents student = gson.fromJson(br, GeneralStudents.class);
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your json file is invalid. You have a coma after each `surname`. Also, could you add the exception/error message ?

Comment: What does *"it does not work"* mean? --- What do you mean by *"BufferedReader does not even read the file"*? How did you figure that? --- What actually happens when you try to run the code?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $ at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224

Answer (score 0):

As theBittor stated: You have to remove the trailing commas after surname. Then the main can read your json.

By the way your readers should be surrounded by try-finally or use the Autoclose feature of Java with

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\student.json"))) {
        GeneralStudents student = gson.fromJson(br, GeneralStudents.class);
}
```